# Why and when does ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator appear?

Tags: java, spring, exception, websocket

I have an implementation using SpringBoot, Stomp and Websockets. Its working fine in general. But sometimes there is a disconnect on the client side and an exception on the server side. And I think it's a broken connection maybe. A disconnect? But I am not sure and I dont know how to handle this exception, as the stacktrace is not part of my classes. It's happening totally inside the framework and I think I can't catch this then.

Any advice?

```
31 Aug 2018 11:23:23 [MessageBroker-2] ERROR springframework.web.socket.handler.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator - Unhandled error for ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator [delegate=LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator [delegate=SubProtocolWebSocketHandler[StompSubProtocolHandler[v10.stomp, v11.stomp, v12.stomp]]]]
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Failed to send message to ExecutorSubscribableChannel[clientInboundChannel]; nested exception is org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
        at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:127) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:104) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.afterSessionEnded(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:643) ~[spring-websocket-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.clearSession(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:482) ~[spring-websocket-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.afterConnectionClosed(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:368) ~[spring-websocket-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:85) ~[spring-websocket-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.afterConnectionClosed(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:72) ~[spring-websocket-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.afterConnectionClosed(ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:78) [spring-websocket-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.close(AbstractSockJsSession.java:216) [spring-websocket-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.close(AbstractSockJsSession.java:188) [spring-websocket-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.TransportHandlingSockJsService$1.run(TransportHandlingSockJsService.java:379) [spring-websocket-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [?:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_181]
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Official java documentation :** 
spring-websocket/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/sockethandler ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LTaE.jpg)

Comment: what does "escape from handler" mean in this case? how can this occur?

Comment: So it seems noone can answer this one? :(